# Adding more than one value to text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to allow users to add a list of 'favourites' to a text box but when adding more than one value it replaces the value already there. Can anybody help? Thanks this is my code:

```
var name

function getFavourite() {

   name = "Student 1, ";

   $('#output').val(name)
   saveFavourites();
}

function getFavourite2() {
   name = "Student 2, ";

   $('#output').val(name)
   saveFavourites();
}

function saveFavourites() {
   var fav = $("#output").val();
   if (fav !== "") {
      localStorage[name] = $("#output").val();
      $("#output").val(name);

   }
}

function loadFavourites() {
   var fav = $("#name").val();
   if (name !== "") {
      $("#output").val(localStorage[name]);
      $("#name").val("");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using val will replace the existing value as you already noticed so i would do something like this if you want to add to that value.

```
$("#output").val($("#output").val() + ', ' + name);
```

At least if i understand you correctly. This would get the excising value and then add the new value to it (in this case with a comma but is  not necessary)

Of course if you need the same element twice or more is better to assign it to a var instead of calling the selector twice.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking into multiple select dropdown, something like this:

http://codepen.io/martynasb/pen/kawxq

Answer (score 0):

You don't an text input, you want a select where you can select multiple values. In html, it's `<select multiple>`.

The plugin I know that provides the best experience for this is is Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#basics

And you don't have to load all the options right away, they can be fetched via ajax easily.